# How to add data to the solr's schema

Tags: solr, solandra

I try to add new data to the solandra according to the solr's schema but I can't find any example about this. My ultimate goal is to integrate solandra with django-solr.

What I understand about the insert and updating in the solr based on the original solr and django-solr is to send the new data on the http protocol to the decent path, for example:

```
http://localhost:8983/solandra/wikipedia/update/json
```

However, when I access the url, the browser keep telling me `HTTP ERROR: 404`.

Can you help me understand the step to add new data and delete the data in the solandra environment?

I also have a look at the reuters-demo, but the procedure to insert data is process in the file of reutersimporter.jar, but I can't see the source as well. So Please help me to understand how the system work in terms of data inserting and deleting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the JSON update handler, this [UpdateJSON](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) page on the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/) has some good examples of inserting data using the JSON handler via curl. Also, the [Indexing Data](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Indexing+Data) section of the [Solr Tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html) shows how you can insert data using the post.jar file that is included with the Solr source.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the solr schema.xml and solrconfig.xml and posting it to solandra?  If you add the JSON handler then this should work.  The reutersdemo uses solrj.  django-solr should work as well.