# Easy GUI way to add data to a Solr index

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm working on the front end of an app that uses Solr for data storage. Currently I have an empty index, but it'd (understandably) be a lot easier for me if some dummy data was returned so I could make sure that it's output correctly on the front end.

If I was working with and RDBMS (let's say postgres) I'd open up a GUI (e.g. pgadmin) and type data manually into a few rows to achieve this goal. I have access to the Solr web interface, but I can't see any obvious call to action saying <kbd>INSERT YOUR DATA HERE</kbd>. The closest thing I can find to an answer on the web is [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680421/how-to-add-data-to-the-solrs-schema), but it's still not quite the <strike>droids</strike> easy GUI-based solution I'm looking for.

So, my question is:  **Is the a way to quickly and easily insert some data equivalent to the RDBMS method mentioned above?**

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Documents+Screen

Comment: Had a similar question at http://superuser.com/questions/770273/phpmyadmin-like-interface-for-apache-solr

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have defined a schema in schema.xml.

SOLR does indeed have a (limited) html GUI, which on a local installation is probably found at `localhost:8983/solr` (default). If you can get to the base admin page, then on the left there is a small combobox where you can select a core/collection. If you click on THAT, then you get a list of options that emerges, and you can pick 'documents' to get a similar GUI to what I think you expect from postgres/RDBMS/whatnot.

`http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/documents` is the URL on a default SOLR installation that I have. This should work as long as you don't have default cores. (Replace collection1 with your collection name and `localhost:8983` with wherever your solr is hosted/the port).

Comment: ok, makes sense so far - the document builder or xml format looks super easy to use, but how do I know what my field names are?